# Elastic search using Java low level rest client

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, java-11

I am trying to move my elastic search (6.6.1), spring boot(2.1.3) application from java 8 to java 11.
Previously, I used high-level java rest client to create and search the index.
Since there exist an issue (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/38299) in modularizing the high level rest client api , I am trying to use low level rest client but I am not able to get any search results.

Please see some of the code pieces -

Search index created using high level rest client

```
           IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("legal3", "scee");
          IndexResponse indexResponse =  
          highlevelclient.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

The query used to search using high level rest client

```
    this.client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200)));
    SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(text, “field1”));
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
    SearchResponse response1 = highlevelclient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Then I used low level rest client to search the same index (index created using high level rest client)

```
        this.client = RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9200)).build();
        String query = "{\"query\":{\"match\":{\"field1\":\"" + text + "\"}}}";
        Response response = lowlevlelclient.performRequest("GET", "legal3", Collections.emptyMap(), new StringEntity(query, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

But it returned only  headers, no real data.

```
{"legal3":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"scee":{"properties”:”field1”:{“type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}}},"settings":{"index":{"number_of_shards":"5","blocks":{"read_only_allow_delete":"true"},"provided_name":"legal3","creation_date":"1552209921359","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"Y_GyoagoTIezgztuUYrlBQ","version":{"created":"6060199"}}}}}
```

I feel that I am doing some mistakes in setting the end point( 2nd param of performRequest) but I  could not find much detail about this.

Could someone please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution. As expected issue was with the endpoint ( 2nd param of `performRequest`)

```
Response response = lowlevelclient.performRequest("GET", "/_search", Collections.emptyMap(), new StringEntity(query, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Now I am getting the expected results

Comment: 7.4.2 client does not contain that method anymore

Comment: @chomp i never used anything other than 6.6.1. In case, if I ever use it then I will update the answer here. Normally whenever they are deprecating a method they must have given the alternative solution in the release notes

Comment: @nantitv where did you mentioned index name ?